# Unable to make WebRTC work in FreeSWITCH

Tags: webrtc, voip, freeswitch, mod-verto

I installed(stable version from RPM Package) FreeSWITCH 1.6.9~64bit in a CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) server as given in the below URL

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/CentOS+7+and+RHEL+7#CentOS7andRHEL7-CentOS7andRHEL7-Stable

However when I start FreeSWITCH, I am getting some errors. I have extracted the errors and listed them below the post.

I purchased a DID number, configured it and I am able to make a conference call using the DID number. I want to provide WebRTC support so that participant can join using Web browser as well.

I guess Verto is needed for WebRTC in FreeSWITCH. I am not sure why mod_rtc.so and mod_verto.so are missing

What can I do to install the missing packages and make WebRTC to work?

```
2016-07-28 15:28:42.072701 [ERR] sofia_glue.c:329 Invalid tls-verify-policy value: none

2016-07-28 15:28:43.573855 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_rtc.so
**/usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_rtc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
2016-07-28 15:28:43.573893 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_verto.so
**/usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_verto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

2016-08-02 15:01:56.519939 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_dialplan_asterisk.so
**/usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_dialplan_asterisk.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

2016-07-28 15:28:44.213518 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_b64.so
**/usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_b64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

2016-07-28 15:28:44.213552 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_opus.so
**/usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_opus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

2016-07-28 15:28:44.216417 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_png.so
**/usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_png.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

2016-07-28 15:28:44.217611 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_lua.so
**/usr/lib64/freeswitch/mod/mod_lua.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

Comment: I would try to build from source and include mod_verto and mod_rtc. For some reason the centOS repo doesn't include rpms for the modules. It's usually easier to get freeswitch up running on debian or ubuntu.

Comment: Try Debian `FreeSWITCH™ 1.6 depends on a number of libraries included with Debian 8, which is now the distribution of choice for FS core development team. Follow the instructions on the Debian 8 Jessie page; refer to Debian Post-Install Tasks for finishing touches`

Answer (score 2):

I am still unable to install Verto and other modules. However, I learnt that Verto is not needed for WebRTC to work. I am able to make call from Web browser to my FreeSWITCH server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried after updating FreeSWITCH version? I am using mod_verto in FreeSWITCH Version 1.6.13~64bit and it works for me.

**However, I learnt that Verto is not needed for WebRTC to work.** --> Yes, you are right. Actually, Verto is WebRTC based client for communication with FreeSWITCH.

Try using latest FreeSWITCH version source code for make mod_verto work.